# how to find how many time a digit 0-9 appears in an integer

Tags: c, ansi-c

i need some help with a code, as the heahline is saying i need to find how many times a digit 0-9 appears in an integer and print it like so:
300
in a base of 10
0:2
1:0
2:0
3:1
4:0
5:0
6:0
7:0
8:0
9:0
i have try'ed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

int num, div=1, rem, count=0, i;
printf("Enter Number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
div = num;
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    div = num;
    while(div!< 0)
    {
    rem = div % 10;
    div = div / 10;


    if(i == rem)
    {
        count++;
    }


    if(i == rem && count >= 2)
        {
            printf("\n%d is present %d times", i, count);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

it returns the right answer but not the way i need. thanks for the help!

Comment: So what exactly isn't working, if it does return the right answer?

Comment: So in what way do you need the answer? Can you show us the expected and actual output?

Comment: What should `while(div!< 0)` do?

Comment: You are going through the number 10 times looking for a specific digit, I might have used 10 counters instead and done `counter[rem]++` for each remainder.

Comment: `while(div!< 0)` --> `while(div >=  0)`

Comment: http://ideone.com/zWEKZb

Comment: while(div !< 0) it will not give a divide num under 0, it prints it all wrong...

Comment: the expected out put is [link](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234114/Summer2016/hw/WCFiles/hw2.pdf) the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you count of number of each digit

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int num, div=1, rem,j,  i;
printf("Enter Number: ");
scanf("%d", &num);    //3002
div = num;
int count[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
while(div>0)
{

rem=div%10;
div=div/10;
printf("%d \n",rem);

for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
{

if(rem==i)
{
count[i]=count[i]+1;
}
}
}
for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
{
printf("%d",count[j]);}
return 0;
 }
```

If you enter number 3002, it will give output as 2011000000, indicating 2 0's, 1 two and 1 three.

Comment: your right but yet it prints it wrong... i need to print a column of numbers 0 to 9 and then put how many time beside every number does he appears in the input integer.

Comment: You just need to format the output. In the above code replace the line printf("%d",count[j]);} with printf("%d:%d \n",j,count[j]);}

Comment: thats solved it thanks! now if i need to add the base 2 of the number? i mean in the number 300 there is 5 zeros and 4 ones how can i add it?

Comment: In base 2, you have only 0 and 1. So you can change the loops from 0-9 to 0-1 and again count will display the number of 0 and 1 in the series.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. You're cheating yourself.

Comment: i just asket for help on how to it, i done most of the code myself... you were a student your self i guess so asking for help is learning...