# How do you check how many times each digit from 0 - 9 appears in an input number

Tags: c++

I just can't seem to come up with a way to go about this problem. I've been searching online for logic for this but no luck. One way would be to store the number in an array then comparing each value of the array but in this case your only limited to enter a limited amount of digits because of the size of the array and all.

pls help!

**EDIT:** Thanks for the suggested question but unfortunately I was too dumb to understand how it worked by just looking at the code :( I'm here to learn how to actually do this which is why I need explanations on doing it that way and I couldn't find any explanations there. Not to mention it was C code :p.

**EDIT 2:** I finally get it. After reading through what @rturrado said several times and wrecking my brain to actually make sense of this. After that I did a couple random numbers with that method. Now that I finally know how to go through each digit in an integer, I can finally go about checking the frequency by using a loop for each digit from 0 - 9. In this loop I'd run through the whole integer number for each iteration and plus one to a variable each time each time any digit in the number is equal to the outer loop variable.

Annnd.....I'm just gonna leave this here incase another poor sod like me comes around trying to make sense of things :)

Comment: "pls help!" is not a valid question.  What have you tried?  Also: *I've been searching online for logic for this but no luck.* -- You should "search for logic" by taking out paper and pencil, drawing 10 empty boxes, taking a sample number, and filling in the boxes the number of digits matching each empty box as you go through the sample number.   If you can't see the pattern that is occurring (hint: adding 1 to the right box each time you see the digit), then I don't know what else to mention.  Then you write the code to do this.

Comment: Hint: if you keep on dividing a number by 10, and getting the modulus of the division, you walk each number's digit from right to left.

Comment: If the issue is with "how do I extract each digit?", then please state that in the title.  That would whittle down the "pls help!" to a more focused issue.

Comment: @rturrado: Assuming the number is a non-negative integer.

Comment: _"I've been searching online for logic for this but no luck."_  Try searching for your exact title in this question.  The top results offer exact code to solve this problem.

Comment: *"but in this case your only limited to enter a limited amount of digits because of the size of the array"*.  You will have limitation anyway, integer type are limited. and with string, you don't work with integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find how many time a digit 0-9 appears in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931218/how-to-find-how-many-time-a-digit-0-9-appears-in-an-integer)

Comment: One way would be to have 10 counters, perhaps as an array, and increment the corresponding counter each time you see a particular digit.

Comment: @Themeiscool I use fingers for such a task.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pls help! is like my signature catchphrase. Oh wow! I get that your supposed to run a loop for each digit and add 1 each time you see it in the number. Now then how do I actually do this? Like how does one actually go through a number for checking individual digits? Sorry if this sounds dumb but I am noob :(

Comment: I wonder who upvoted the question?!

Comment: @rturrado Ahhhh......That seems to be exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a hecking lot. Though.......What do you mean by modulus part? The remainder of division by 10 is actually the right most digit? So how are you gonna divide the number the next time for the next digit to the right?

Comment: @Jarod42 isn't it still better to not be limited to creating an array of a thousand elements? Not to mention the inconvenience of hitting enter after typing each digit.

Comment: For input, you mostly have 2 choices, integer type (with such limitations (we only have fixed-width integer)) or string type (here, you can work directly with digits) (but it is no longer a "number", pedantically).

Comment: Yeah I get it. Working with strings in this case would be a piece of cake. But I really wanna know how to go through each digit in an integer now. If on @rturrado tried explaining that but I still don't completely get it :(

Comment: @Themeiscool By modulus I meant remainder of a division (`%` operator in C++). And if you do, for example, `int r = n % 10; n = n / 10;` in a loop, you grab the current digit with `r` and you "update" your input number `n` for the next iteration. You got an example in Vadim's answer.

Comment: @rturrado Aww heck you clarifying it like this before would have saved me a lot of leg (or should I say brain?) work of figuring it out myself. Thanks a hecking lot though your the main reason I was able to get it.

Comment: @rturrado So you left me to figure it out on my own on purpose? -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you would like to have an explanation and not just a code dump or some comments.

So, let me try to explain you.

As you know: Numbers like 12345 in a base 10 numbering system or decimal system are build of a digit and a power of 10. Mathematically you could write 12345 also a `5*10^0 + 4*10^1 + 3*10^2 + 2*10^3 + 1*10^4`.

Or, we can write:

```
number = 0;
number = number + 1;
number = number * 10;
number = number + 2;
number = number * 10;
number = number + 3;
number = number * 10;
number = number + 4;
number = number * 10;
number = number + 5;
```

That is nothing new. But it is important to understand, how to get back the digits from a number.

Obviously we need to make an integer division by 10 somewhen. But this alone does not give us the digits. If we perform a division o 12345 by 10, then the result is 1234.5. And for the intger devision it os 1234 with a rest of 5. And now, we can see that the rest is the digit that we are looking for.

And in C++ we have a function that gives us the rest of an integer division. It is the modulo operator %.

Let us look, how this works:

```
int number = 12345;
int digit = number % 10;     // Result will be 5

// Do something with digit

number = number / 10;   // Now number is 1234 (Integer division will truncate the fraction)
digit = number % 10;        // Result is now 4

// Do something with digit

number = number / 10;   // Now number is 123 (Integer division will truncate the fraction)
digit = number % 10;        // Result is now 3

// Do something with digit

number = number / 10;   // Now number is 12 (Integer division will truncate the fraction)
digit = number % 10;        // Result is now 2

// Do something with digit

number = number / 10;   // Now number is 1 (Integer division will truncate the fraction)
digit = number % 10;        // Result is now 1


number = number / 10;   // Now number is 0, and we can stop the operation.
```

And later we can do all this in a loop.

Like with

```
int number = 12345;
while (number > 0) {
    int digit = number % 10;     // Extract next digit from number

    // Do something with digit

    number /= 10;
}
```

And thats it. Now we extracted all digits.

---

Next is counting. We have 10 different digits. So, we could now define 10 counter variables like "int counterFor0, counterFor1, counterFor2 ..... , counterFor9" and the compare the digit with "0,1,2,...9" and then increment the related counter. But that is too much typing work.

But, luckily, we have arrays in C++. So we can define an array with 10 counters like: `int counterForDigit[10]`. OK, understood.

You remember that we had in the above code a comment "// Do something with digit
". And this we will do now. If we have a digit, then we use that as an index in our array and increment the related counter.

So, finally. One possible solution would be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // Test number. Can be anything
    int number = 12344555;

    // Counter for our digits
    int counterForDigits[10]{};  // The {} will initialize all values in the array with 0  

    // Extract all digits
    while (number > 0) {

        // Get digit
        int digit = number % 10;

        // Increment related counter
        counterForDigits[digit]++;

        // Get next number
        number /= 10;
    }
    // Show result
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
        std::cout << k << " : " << counterForDigits[k] << '\n';
}
```

If you do not want to show 0 outputs, then please add `if (counterForDigits[k] > 0)` after the `for` statement.

If you should have further questions, then please ask

Comment: Awww thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. You were so nice to go over the absolute basics of things to make sure I got everything correctly :) . I never thought about places in decimal are multiples of 10. This really clears up on why the division with 10 and the remainder. Thanks man you really made my day by helping me get it so well :)

Answer (score 2):

I can offer the solution of your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
void showContentVector(vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void showContentMap(map<int, int>& input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        cout<<iterator->first<<" : "<<iterator->second<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    int number=1004;
    vector<int> digits;
    map<int, int> repetitions;
    while(number)
    {
        digits.push_back(number%10);
        number/=10;
    }
    cout<<"digits <- ";
    showContentVector(digits);
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<digits.size(); ++i)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<digits.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(digits[i]==digits[j])
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        repetitions.insert(pair<int, int>(digits[i], count));
    }
    cout<<"repetitions <- "<<endl;
    showContentMap(repetitions);
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
digits <- 4, 0, 0, 1, 
repetitions <- 
0 : 2
1 : 1
4 : 1
```

Comment: Aww thanks! You guys are really nice. though this code consists of things which I can't make any sense of with where I am in my learning journey right now like vector and map and stuff. I really wanna understand how it happens and I even found a simpler complete solution on the internet https://www.w3resource.com/cpp-exercises/for-loop/cpp-for-loop-exercise-59.php But now I just don't get the moving through a number to get each digit in it part  :(  I really wanna get this stuff.

Comment: If this solution has helped you, mark this question as **solved**.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

- reading your input as a string,
- checking if the input is a valid number (contains only digits),
- then counting the digits using an array of 10 elements (one for each digit from 0 to 9).

A couple of notes on the code below:

1. Why `counts[c - '0']`? Subscript operator, `[]`, will use a `size_t` as a parameter. If you don't want to have an access out of the bounds of the array, you should use an index between `size_t` `0` and `9`. But you are reading characters from a string. If you just use a `char` from `'0'` to `'9'` as an index, the corresponding `size_t` value will be between `48` and `57` (ASCII codes for `'0'` and `'9'` `char` respectively). By subtracting `c - '0'` you'll end up with an index between `size_t` `0` and `9`. More difficult to explain than to understand I guess!
2. Notice also `counts[c - '0']` returns a [reference to the element in the array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at). That's why `counts[c - '0']++` actually modifies the array contents.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/KrzW6x6od)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // all_of
#include <array>
#include <iostream>  // cout

int main()
{
    auto is_digit = [](char c) { return c >= '0' and c <= '9'; };

    const std::string n{"122333444455555"};

    if (not std::all_of(std::cbegin(n), std::cend(n), is_digit))
    {
        std::cout << "Error: input string is not a valid number.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::array<int, 10> counts{};
    for (auto c : n)
    {
        counts[c - '0']++;
    }
    for (int i{0}; i < counts.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Number of " << i << "s in input number: " << counts[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach:
Assuming you want to get the number of digits of the decimal equivalent of the number, you can convert the int to a string, then count the digit characters:

```
#include <string>
[...]
char digit = '3'; // or any digit
int num = 321523; // or any number

// convert to decimal string
std::string str_num = to_string(num);

// count digits
int digit_count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<str_num.length(); i++)
    if(str_num[i] == digit)
        digit_count++;

// digit_count should now be equal to 2
```